# If/else to test for home in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an image banner in the header of my custom WP theme, on pages only (not posts). I need this banner to be different on the home page. I've created a front-page template and have this:

```
    <?php if (is_front_page()){ ?>
        <div class="banner">
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="">
                </a>
        </div><!-- #banner -->

    <?php else { ?>
        <div class="banner">
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="">
                </a>
            <?php endif; // End header image check. ?>
        </div><!-- #banner -->
```

I'm using the same image twice here just to test, but get a heap of errors. My php isn't great. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not without you telling us what isn't working / what errors you are getting. _"A heap of errors"_ isn't very informative.

Comment: If this is an exact copy of your code, you should at least remove the last 3 lines (one is empty but still remove it)

Comment: Sorry, here's a screen shot of the errors in WP.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6w1lphv7bvbwt8/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-04%20at%208.58.56%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: You've missed a closing brace before the else

Comment: you have to add a closing brace before the else and end of your else section, also an endif is missing

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say here, just replace you're code with this:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()){ ?>
    <div class="banner">
        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="">
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- #banner -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="banner">
        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="">
            </a>
        <?php endif; // End header image check. ?>
    </div><!-- #banner -->
<?php } ?>
```

To enlighten a bit:

- You forgot a closing `}` before `else {`
- You were missing an `endif;` before `</div><!-- #banner -->`